# AS3 Working with long movie clips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an external, 40 minute video that is on the timeline as an FLVPlayBack component. Video is monitored with an Event.COMPLETE listener. However, flash is limited to 16000 frames and the video is way over that limit. How can I overcome this problem? There will be 6 more videos with different lengths each with Event.COMPLETE listeners. Is my only option splitting the video into 8 parts and call one after another? Considering combined lenght of the videos are over 2 hours. The project will be published as an Air Application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 16.000 frames is a flash limitation. You can have a master Flash which loads each of the other flash files, each one of the child flash files will contain only one video.

Comment: But still...to your reference "each of the other flash files", meaning each fla containing a video will still be more than 16000 frames in lenght when a long video gets imported to it.

Comment: Why don't you load the video instead of SWF?

Comment: Can you provide more info or an example please? You mean using NetConnection? (just read about it after your post)

Comment: You can check this URL: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d4e.html

Comment: Will apply and report back. Thank you.